# Show DIV element in Twitter Bootstrap Modal along with DOM

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple `div` tag, that contains a button. When ever user clicks on this button it simply shows an alert.

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" />
</div>
```

and I also have a empty twitter bootstrap modal.

```
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
         <h3>Modal header</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
</div>
```

I have a second button, when ever the user clicks on it, it opens the bootstrap modal. I want to show "myDiv" in bootstrap modal when ever the user clicks on the second button. I want "myDiv" to be present in when ever modal opens and also I want to be present in my HTML document. So that I can always access it with out creating second button in modal.

Any idea how can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you were going for so basically on the modal show we append that button to the modal body.

```
$("#myDiv") .appendTo(".modal-body");
```

but we aren't done because after modal close we need to get it back in the body so we do:

```
 $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
$("#myDiv") .prependTo("body");     
})
```

**Here** is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zcb3h/2/

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Thunda. If I append myDiv to .modal-body then there will be two buttons with same id's right ?

Comment: @user3191903 No appendTo will move that div inside of the body. It doesn't duplicate it so you should be fine. :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Thunda.. Now It all make sense to me. Learnt about AppendTo and PrependTo. I never understand those concepts till now.. Thanks a ton. I owe you a big help :)